# Image is Not Getting Saved at Destination Folder

Tags: php, image, upload, path

I am a Beginner in PHP and i want to Upload image via PHP and want to save it in destination folder.

i will show you the correct path of the folder where i want the image to be saved, but its only getting saved in database and the image file is not getting save in folder.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        include ('dbconfig.php');

        $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $detail=$_POST['des'];

        if($image!=null)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"/Tomar/php/a/uploads/".$_FILES['image']['name']);
            }


    $entry = "INSERT INTO aboutstudent(stuimg, stuname, studetail) VALUES ('$image','$name','$detail')";
    $result = mysql_query($entry); 
    }
?>
```

and i want to save my images at below path:

```
D:/wamp/www/Tomar/php/a/uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get code example from [Image Upload in PHP](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/660367/PHP-image-uploader-with-display-insert)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have used  **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

```
<form action=" " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and your "uploads" directory has **777 permission**.

Referrence : [File upload in php](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: Hey Mitul, Thanks for answering i have already included the enctype tag in html form. but i think i am doing something wrong in path which is written in "move_uploaded_file" line.

Comment: check your error by echo(ing) $_FILES['userfile']['error']; and try to print your destination path and make sure directory folder is available with proper name